# Yum install is not working on old fedora-15

Tags: fedora

I installed old fedora 15. I know that is obselete.
I am trying to install gcc and other development tools.
But repositories are not working with yum.
What to do ???

Answer (score 0):

Fedora 15 https://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/15/

Fedora 15 updates https://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/updates/15/

64bit example `/etc/yum/repos.d/fedora15.repo`

```
[fedora15]
name=Fedora15-x86_64 
baseurl=https://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/15/Everything/x86_64/os/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1

[fc15-updates]
name=Fedora15-updates-x86_64
baseurl=https://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/updates/15/x86_64/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
```

Please move all files in /etc/yum/repos.d/ to a backup directory, or simply delete the files. And create a new file `fedora15.repo` with the above text. If the keys have expired, then edit gpgcheck=1 to gpgcheck=0